# Is there any way to set lifetime of refresh token to infinite in django-rest-framework-simplejwt?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

I am using django-rest-framework-simplejwt for authentication for my Django project. I have done some research but could not find a solution for that. In the documentation, the format to set refresh token is in time delta. Is it possible to set the refresh token to not expire at all?